# XTK volume dimension on pixel

Tags: xtk

I use this function var  _dimensions = v.dimensions; to extract the different dimensions of a volume(.gz.nii) ,Now i would to know if there is a relation bitween the dimension on pixel of the image and the dimension for emample hight_px = A * dimention[1] , A a var

Thanks a lot,
AMAL

Answer (score 0):

there is a X.renderer2D.xy2ijk function which takes canvas coordinates and returns the image IJK coordinates. so if dimensions are [10,20,30] the ijk runs between 0..10,0..20,0..30

Comment: Can you give me an example that demonstrate how we can use this function (X.renderer2D.xy2ijk) Best,AMAL